# Adding continuation pages for overflowing sections

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, appendices

Suppose I have a collection of sections (each starting after a `\newpage`) such that the total content of some of the sections is more than one page.  What I want to do is to get LaTeX to recognize this is the case, cap the section at one page, and put the rest of the material in an appendix at the end. So, in the end, each section should just be a single page in the main body of the document, with appropriate pointers to the appendix, with the rest of the material removed to the appendix.

Is there a package/code snippet that can do this? What I have no idea how to do is to how to detect that the section has gone over a page.

I am not sure how to make an MWE for this, but if anybody wants any specific examples or has suggestions for an MWE, I would be happy to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\def\a{Red green blue black white cyan magenta yellow. }
\def\b{\subsection{zzz}\a\a\a One two three four five six \Roman{subsection}. }
\def\c{\b\b\b\a\a\b\par\a\a\a\b\b\b\a\a\b\b\par}

\newbox\appbox
\global\setbox\appbox\vbox{}

\def\sec#1{%
\def\sectitle{#1}%
\clearpage
\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\bgroup\section{#1}}

\def\endsec{\vfill\par\egroup\egroup
\vsplit0 to \textheight\vfill
\ifdim\ht0>0pt
\global\setbox\appbox\vbox{\unvbox\appbox
\clearpage
\section*{\thesection\ continued: \sectitle}%
\unvbox0}%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{sec}{AAAAA}
\c\c
\end{sec}

\begin{sec}{BB BB}
\b
\end{sec}

\begin{sec}{CCCC}
\c\c\b\b\c
\end{sec}

\part{appendix}

\unvbox\appbox
\end{document}
```